# Configure Cisco 877 as bridge between Internet and Cisco ASA 5505

Tags: networking, cisco, router, bridge, adsl

ISP ADSL ---- Cisco 877 Router ---- Cisco ASA 5505

I have the above connection.   I'd like to avoid using NAT on the Cisco 837 router, and just put the ASA directly on the Internet.  However, I have to use the 837 to connect to the ISP - the ASA doesn't have an ADSL interface.

I know how to configure the ASA to handle the pppoe connection, but not how to configure the 837 to act as a bridge between ADSL and Ethernet.

Is this what is called RFC1483 bridging?

Will the following config allow the ASA to do all the pppoe negotiation, and leave the 877 doing nothing more than bridging ethernet and ADSL?:

```
no ip routing

interface Ethernet0 
  no ip address
  no ip directed-broadcast   
  bridge-group 1

encapsulation aal5snap

bridge-group 1

bridge 1 protocol ieee
```

Unfortunately, this is our only site with an 800 series router connecting to the internet, so I am not very familiar with it, and I won't be able to test the configuration  out properly until I get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the config I used, and it worked:

```
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging message-counter syslog
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
no ip routing
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
interface ATM0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
 pvc 8/35
  encapsulation aal5snap
 !
 bridge-group 1
!
interface FastEthernet0
!
interface FastEthernet1
!
interface FastEthernet2
!
interface FastEthernet3
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 bridge-group 1
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
bridge 1 protocol ieee
!
line con 0
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
scheduler max-task-time 5000
end
```

Source was [Cisco DSL Router Configuration and Troubleshooting Guide - Cisco DSL Router: PC Acting as a PPPoE Client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk175/tk15/technologies_configuration_example09186a008071a78c.shtml) which needed adjusting slightly for the 877.